# Web Page Not Loading from Dockerized MERN Stack on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently facing an issue where my web page is not loading from a Dockerized MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) stack hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. I have successfully configured my backend and frontend in separate Docker containers and they seem to be running well, but I can't access my web application through the browser.

**Environment:**

- AWS EC2 instance
- Docker containers for both frontend (React) and backend (Node.js)
- MongoDB Atlas as the database
- Frontend running on NGINX, exposed on port 3000
- Backend exposed on port 4000
- Security Group inbound rules set to allow HTTP on port 80 from all sources (`0.0.0.0/0`)

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=${MONGO_URI}
  frontend:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

**Symptoms:**

- Can't load the web page when accessing the EC2's public IP with the
  specified port (e.g., http://<EC2_IP>:3000).
- Docker logs show no errors for both containers.
- Backend connects to MongoDB Atlas successfully.
- curl on EC2 instance fails to connect to localhost port 443: curl:
  (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Couldn't connect to
  server.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

-Verified that the Docker containers for both frontend and backend are running without errors.

-Checked MongoDB Atlas connection from the backend, which is successful.

-Ensured AWS EC2 Security Group inbound rules allow traffic on port 80 (HTTP).

-Attempted to access the web page using the public IP address of the EC2 instance.

**Questions:**

- Could there be an issue with how I'm exposing my Docker containers or
  with the NGINX configuration in my frontend container?
- Is there a specific AWS EC2 or Docker network setting that I might be
  overlooking which could cause the site to be inaccessible from the
  browser?
- Are there additional logs or debugging steps I should look into to
  diagnose the issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm relatively new to Docker and AWS, so it's possible I might have missed something fundamental.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I modified the EC2 Security Group inbound rules. Instead of an HTTP rule, I created a TCP rule for port 3000 and it worked properly.